# Generic User for Excel Connection String

Tags: string, excel, connection

Is it possible to have a generic user reference in the data connection string of an Excel data connection?

I have a external reference to another workbook that I would like to share with my colleagues, and in the collaboration software that we use there is a path for each user's synced folder, such as:

`C:\Users\"Username"\....`

Is there a prompt similar to %USERPROFILE% that I could use in this instance?  Here is a full connection string example:

```
DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=C:\Users\"Username"\...\File.xlsx;DefaultDir=C:\Users\"Username"\...;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate `C:\Users\Username` use: `environ("HOMEDRIVE") & environ("HOMEPATH")`

see [Environ Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264486.aspx)
and also Windows APIs & Wscript at [Daily Dose of Excel - Get the Path to My Documents in VBA](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/02/26/get-the-path-to-my-documents-in-vba/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @EEM!  Unfortunately, I am not using VBA to create the data connection parameters within the worksheet (and I am simply using the Data Connection wizard to define the path).  I think I have a temporary solution, but I might need to resort to VBA in the end!